# Finding the converges of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Problem 69, from Calculus by Larson, 9e.

> $$a_n = \left(1+\frac{k}{n} \right)^n$$

I know that is $e^k$, but that is not a fixed number, is this legal?

Doesn't it have to converge to a specific number?

Comment: well, we assumed (i supposed) that $k$ is fixed, so $e^k$ is fixed number

Comment: It would also have to be the limit and n approaches infinity. Think of k as a constant. Similar to the constant of integration (+C) this k is just a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^k$ is a fixed number, as $k$ is here an arbitrary constant.

As you see you are having $a_n$ so there is only a dependence from $n$